# Give all the ways of factoring $x^2$ into polynomials of degree 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_9[x]$; in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 24 Exercise C7.

> Give all the ways of factoring $x^2$ into polynomials of degree 1 in $\mathbb{Z}_9[x]$; in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Attempt:

In $\mathbb{Z}_9[x]$, there are 2 ways:

$x^2\,\equiv (x)(x) \equiv(x+3)(x+6).$

In $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, there is only 1 way:

$x^2\, \equiv (x)(x)$.

Correct?

Comment: A) Why did you exclude $x\cdot x$? B) Often factorization differing by unit factors only are treated as the same.

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen, my bad, Thanks!

Comment: Almost always factorizations that differ only by unit (invertible) factors are considered equivalent, e.g. $\,fg = (uf)(u^{-1}g).\,$ Your lists include many such duplicate equivalent factorizations.

Comment: Thanks, @BillDubuque and Jyrki Lahtonen on the duplicates.  Does it look right now?

Comment: No, e.g.  $\,(2x+3)(5x+6) = (x+6)(x+3)\,$ and same for others, by scaling so the lead coef's are $1$ (here multiply $x+2$ by $5$ and $5x+6$ by $5^{-1} = 2\ \ \ $

Comment: Got it.  Didn't know this is the convention.  Thanks again.